# Find -type f with restrictions

Tags: linux, unix, find

I have the following find command to find all files in a Volume:

```
find ./ -type f
```

How would I exclude all files that start with `.` ? Also, I do want to include **folders** that being with `.` For example:

- Include `.Trashes/file.php`
- Do not include `folder/.hidden_file.php`

What would be the correct `find` command for this?

Comment: A 'Volume' is not a directory.  `find . ...` will find files in and below the current directory, but certainly not all files on the Volume containing the current directory.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To exclude all files whose names begin with `.` :

```
find ./ -type f ! -name '.*'
```

This will search in all directories (even if their names start with a dot), descending from the current directory, for regular files whose names do not begin with a dot (`! -name '.*'`).

Comment: This was useful as I needed to do something similar in the pwd without including the directories. `find -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -type d`  did the trick.